# Build standalone NPM Module with KotlinJS

Tags: npm, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

When I follow the guide [Create a multiplatform library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-create-lib.html) I manage to get Jar to be used in Kotlin/JVM side, but the npm module doesn't look good - it is generatesd with physical paths to dependenices to several `kotlin` packages:

```
{
  "name": "metalib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "kotlin/metalib.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dukat": "0.5.8-rc.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "kotlin": "file:C:\\Users\\ ... \\build\\js\\packages_imported\\kotlin\\1.4.31",
    "kotlin-test-js-runner": "file:C:\\Users\\ ... \\build\\js\\packages_imported\\kotlin-test-js-runner\\1.4.31",
    "kotlin-test": "file:C:\\Users\\ ... \\build\\js\\packages_imported\\kotlin-test\\1.4.31"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": []
}
```

Where `...` is full path to Multiplatform project.

I tried to build the library with `npm pack` and install into webapp, but app tries to look for the deps on these paths.

Is there a way to build clean, standalone (or at least with dependenices resolvable by npmjs.com) module with KotlinJS/Multiplatform?

**UPD:**

`build.gradle.kts` content

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.31"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnit()
        }
    }
    js(LEGACY) {
        browser {
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    webpackConfig.cssSupport.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
        val nativeMain by getting
        val nativeTest by getting
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste your build.gradle file?

Comment: @andylamax sure, but it's pretty the default gradle file for kotlin multiplatform project without any changes.